# The mapping $P$ is a measure on, what?

Tags: probability

If $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ is a [probability space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_space#Definition), do we say that $P$ is a measure on $\Omega$ or $\mathcal{F}$?

I know that it is a measure on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$, but I want to be sure which one of them it is to be precise.

Comment: View $P$ as a mapping (set function), it is more precise to say $P$ is on $\mathscr{F}$.

Comment: We say $P$ is a measure on the measurable space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$.

Comment: Usually we say it is a measure on the measurable space, which includes the underlying set as well as the $\sigma$-algebra. It isn't really wrong to say it is a measure on just the $\sigma$-algebra (since that *is* its domain, after all). It is definitely wrong to say it is a measure on the underlying set (although in cases where the $\sigma$-algebra is "standard", we do say this anyway).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rigorously speaking, $P$ is a measure on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$. It can't just be a measure on $\Omega$ because it's not necessairly defined on every subset.

Colloquially, on the other hand, people sometimes speak of a measure $P$ on a set $\Omega$. Either it is understood that the $\sigma$-algebra is something standard (like the entire power set $\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$, or the Borel $\sigma$-algebra), or else it is understood that the measurable sets are implicitly included in the measure $P$. In this latter case, you can think of $P$ as being a [partial function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function).

Answer (score 1):

If $(\Omega,\mathscr F,\mathbb P)$ is a probability space, then the probability measure $\mathbb P:\mathscr F\to[0,1]$ is a function whose domain is $\mathscr F$, satisfying $\mathbb P(\varnothing)=0$, $\mathbb P(\Omega)=1$, and $\mathbb P(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb P(A_n)$ whenever $A_1,A_2,\ldots\in\mathscr F$ are pairwise disjoint.

On the other hand, even if you say that “$\mathbb P$ is a measure on $\Omega$,” which one might say is incorrect from a purist’s point of view, everybody will know what you’re talking about as long as the underlying $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr F$ is clearly understood.